# Hello! I want to print the sequences obtained into a 2D matrix, however, I don't know how to convert the list into an array. Could someone help me?

Tags: matrix

```
import random

def matrixv(rows, columns):

    matrixv = []

    for r in range(rows):

        local = []

        for c in range(columns):

            r = "".join([random.choice("ATCG") for j in range(random.randint(1, 10))])

            local.append(r)

        matrixv.append(local)

    return matrixv
```

Running it:

```
n, m = 5, 4

result = matrixv(n, m)

print(result)



  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/jl1VE.png
```

Comment: Can you share what's your expected output?  given the n, m = 5, 4 in this case.

Comment: The code run, but the output is the same... It's showing me a string of ATCGs. However, I'd like to see the output as a matrix of 5x4.

Comment: ["Can Someone Help Me" is not an actual question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The original code have some problems: 1) use the same function name as the variable `matrixv`;  2) it also reuse the `r` in the for-loop, and later to store the creating string.

Maybe you can try this code to see if that's what you want:

```
def create_matrix(row, col):
    matrix = []

    for r in range(row):
        tmp = []

        for c in range(col):
            s = "".join([random.choice("ATCG") for j in range(random.randint(1, 10))])
            tmp.append(s)

        matrix.append(tmp)

    return matrix
```

Calling the function:

```
>>> print(create_matrix(5, 4))
```

#### Edit: above code is to correct the OP, next is to do true 2D:

```
from import choice, randint

def create_matrix(row, col):
    matrix = [[''.join([choice('ATCG') for _ in range(randint(1,10))])
                  for _ in range(col)]
                  for _ in range(row)]
    return matrix
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I got this output ['TCGGT', 'GTCTTCAGAG', 'ATAGATTAG', 'AGG'], ['GCTCCCC', 'GCTTAAGTGA', 'ATCTTA', 'T']... However, I'd like to see this result as a matrix 5x4.

Comment: It's quite simple to make a minor changes. Do want to try first? I just try to correct your original post to make it work, it's seems to be working?

Comment: Yes, it's working. I'm a quite new in programming so, the simplest things are complicated to me ( However, I understand the code that you sent me.

Comment: For 2D matrix, you can try this - `matrix = [[0 for x in range(c)] for _ in range(r)]`